# Serve react bundles on basis of http response

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have an requirement where I want to make a http call from server A to server B and on the basis of response I want to serve react bundle A or B.

Here, I don't want to use express or node. As per my analysis there is no way without a backend server language like node.

Could you please confirm if I am right or there is any way to do that?

Please find the picture for more clarity. So on server A I don't want to use any language except html and react.

[image]